# Get a $ in front of a variable within a .map() - React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project in react using mongodb, and I am charting some of my data using google react charts. One of my charts contains a variable for total number of sales (`x.sales`), and I was wondering if anyone knew a way to add a $ to that variable in my chart?

```
<div>
            <h2 className="graphname">Daily Sales</h2>
              {summary.dailySales.length === 0 ? (
                <MessageBox>No Sale</MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <Chart
                  width="100%"
                  height="400px"
                  chartType="AreaChart"
                  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>
                  }
                  data={[
                    ['Date', 'Sales'],
                    ...summary.dailySales.map((x) => [x._id, x.sales]),
                  ]} 
                  options={{
                    vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
                  }}
                >
                
                </Chart>
                
              )}
            </div>
```

I tried `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}).format(x.sales)`, but that didn't work. I would really appreciate any advice on how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string literal.

```
data={[
 ['Date', 'Sales'],
 ...summary.dailySales.map((x) => [x._id, `$${x.sales}`])]}
```

Or you can concatenate the strings

```
data={[
 ['Date', 'Sales'],
 ...summary.dailySales.map((x) => [x._id, "$" + x.sales.toString()])]}
```

Or you can use the international number [formatter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) but ensure x.sales is a number

```
data={[
     ['Date', 'Sales'],
     ...summary.dailySales.map((x) =>{

//Ensure it's a number and not a string
const number = parseFloat(x.sales).toFixed(2)
const formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(number)
return[x._id, formatted ]
}
```

Then pass the data to your chart component